# How do I verify that the Linux kernel is not freezing when uploading or downloading large data over the ethernet interface?

Tags: networking, kernel, tcp, udp, packet

How to verify if the Linux kernel is doing what it's saying for network interfaces? I have one network interface `eth0` which has hardware support to do 1GB full-duplex.

I have prepared 2 box.

Now when I do normal x11vnc from box to box after 1 or 2 minute later both system get frozen, unless I power off and power on.

Now, how can I verify it's an issue of the Linux kernel and it's unable to do data upload and download of 1GB?

Is there any way to test accurate 1GB packet transfer live from PC1 to PC2 over TCP or UDP and do a full-duplex test, if the kernel is not causing frozen or crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for upload/download testing i found the `iperf` tool quite useful:

```
 user@hostA: iperf -s

 user@hostB: iperf -c hostA
```

if the kernel is really the problem, you will usually get a `kernel oops` before the crash. the main problem is accessing anything the kernel prints to the console, when you are using a graphical interface (and cannot switch to the console once the system is frozen)

for starters, you could switch to a `TTY` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) before running the network tests, and see whether you get some printout when the system freezes.